# all meshes are selected, yet they don't appear on UV EDITING

Tags: uv

[image]

as y'all can see, these are all my meshes selected (they are 3, separate, meshes)
when i go into UV EDITING MODE, select all three, they don't show up on left window D:
i've been trying for hours on end now with no sucess.
if i join them, they loose the textures and uv maps keep on not appearing.
for it to get to the other game, i have to join them, but with the textures already D:
the problem is: i can't see the uv map on the left, which is weird Ç=Ç
does anyone know how to solve it, please? :c
it would honest to goku mean the whole wide world -q
(i have to do it on blender 2.78 as it is the only version the game i'm converting to accepts it Ç=Ç)

edit: the uv maps now showing but not highlighting everythin', on the right or the left. when i join the mesh into one, it looses part of the mesh, even though it appears on the right, the uv map is nowhere to be seen.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the UV maps were all different names. When I renamed them, it solved everything, and then after I joined.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the procedures you took to solve the issue? Perhaps describe the steps and show a few screenshots

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because the object that is showing the UV map is the one that was active among the multi-object selection when you first went into edit mode (but I do not know much about multi-object edit mode).

Either that or the other UV maps are transformed several texture-widths away. Zoom out on the UV map.

As of later blenders, you can thankfully join meshes and the UV maps will merge, but AFAIK no-can-do on 2.79 :-(

Maybe load into later blender, join, then send back to 2.79?

that's what I know...

Comment: i tried to do that, but the uv maps are different in each of the version (thus the uv map not working with the texture in the latest blenders Ç=Ç I CRI). i can now see all the uv maps, but it doesn't highlight all the parts, so there's daaaaat XD (as i showed in my edit :3:)